# How to call PUT method using httpwebrequest?

Tags: asp.net, rest, wcf, httpwebrequest

Tried Code:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/RestfulTutorialService/Service.svc/Post");
            request.Method = "PUT";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {

                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var payload = serializer.Serialize(objBlogPost);
                writer.Write(payload);

            }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var responseCode = response.StatusCode;
```

Error:The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

My service is a Restful service. Below is the method being called.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "/Post", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void UpdateBlogPost(BlogPost post);
```

Comment: use postman or other tool to check where you're wrong.

Comment: @Div using post worked for me. Is any change required in iis to allow put requests?

Comment: Add `X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT` Read [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPUTOrDELETENotAllowedUseXHTTPMethodOverrideForYourRESTServiceWithASPNETWebAPI.aspx) may this helps you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF error : 405 Method Not Allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228995/wcf-error-405-method-not-allowed)