# WCF service strange behavior

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I have external WCF service, and do not have any access to it. That service is exposing some metadata.

When I generated client and invoked some function several times the method worked perfectly but after that service started throwing `405 Method Not Allowed` error.

The client is using custom binding that is look like:

```
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="IExchangetService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" >
            <textMessageEncoding />
            <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" allowInsecureTransport="false" />
            <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="26214400" maxBufferSize="26214400" transferMode="Buffered" />
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
```

I am surprised by this behavior why for example from 30 calls service successfully executes function 3 times and then simply returns 405 an error? What can this be related to the fall of the service itself? Could I ping it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The information you give doesn't show the problem, maybe it's a cross-domain problem. You can refer to the link below：

[WCF error : 405 Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228995/wcf-error-405-method-not-allowed)

Thanks.